Magento 2 - Prevent admin to overwrite MSI Stock Data when order placed while he was editing product page ( non shipping product)
Currently we have MSI source Qty fields on the Product editing page in Magento Backend.
So, we have both product data and Inventory source data on the same form
and it happens, that admin opens product editing page as he wants to change name/description/media data etc.
but Magento sends whole data on a form to server
and save it all together , re-writing the previous state
thus, if at the time of admin was editing product attributes, order has been placed and inventory has been deducted
saving product form - we just loose this inventory deduction
so, the system will behave like this.
Note:This issue reproduced in the case of wallet payment, credit card means in that scenario order status is in "processing".
Issue is not reproduced in order "pending" status.

Initial state. Qty = 10
Admin opens product page (Qty = 10 )
Customer place an order and make deduction -5 (Qty = 10- 5 = 5)
Customer updates product description and save product (sending Qty =
10 , old value)

